# Strange problem with workbooks.open in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Problem with VBA - workbooks.open. I can't open two files simultaneously.

Hi,

Maybe it's simply the way it's supposed to be, but it seems strange to me. My macro works fine as long as I open only one file in the background using workbooks.open. But when I'm opening the second file, then the first one just closes. Is it normal?

Nothing very complicated. First i Open database:

```
 Set database = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Y:\EME\LW\PL-PIA\AIR\AIRFREIGHT\Zlecenia transportowe\baza_danych_transp.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
```

Then, when I open CMR, the database switches off.

```
 Set CMR = Workbooks.Open("Y:\EME\LW\PL-PIA\AIR\AIRFREIGHT\Zlecenia transportowe\CMR_bis.xlsm")
```

Do I need to create a new instance of excel application for this?

Comment: no. this is not normal. you should be able to open both files

Comment: Is there at code which may be closing the previous file? also try switching workbook names and checking?

Comment: Nope, there's definitely no "close"  action involved. The database remains open exactly until the CMR is prompted to open.

Actually, I've created the simplest of macros to test it, where there are only the two lines I posted in the intiial post.  
When we get to the line when CMR is opened, for some reason excel informs me that "baza_danych already" and asks me whether I want to replace it. Whatever I choose, CMR opens and database disappears.

Comment: How are you defining CMR and database? Try calling database something else as it is a reserved word in some libraries

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I think I know what was causing the problem... I had a macro embedded in CMR that on opening of the workbook was getting some data from database and then was closing it. I dead forgot about it... Thanks for help, switching the names of the worbooks did remind me about it...